# Draw a BitmapFont rotated in libgdx

Tags: java, matrix, rotation, libgdx, bitmap-fonts

I can't seem to figure out how to rotate a Bitmap font correctly. I think you modify the transformation matrix of the SpriteBatch. However, trying to rotate that rotates the text around some point, and I don't know how to rotate it relative to the text itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try the following code:

```
Matrix4 mx4Font = new Matrix4();
BitmapFont font;
SpriteBatch spriteFont;

font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/font/agencyFB.fnt"), Gdx.files.internal("data/font/agencyFB.png"), true); //must be set true to be flipped
mx4Font.setToRotation(new Vector3(200, 200, 0), 180);
spriteFont.setTransformMatrix(mx4Font);
spriteFont.begin();
font.setColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
font.draw(spriteFont, "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog", 100, 110);
spriteFont.end();
```

Comment: You should elaborate on what the vector means when doing setToRotation

Answer (score 5):

You can create a glyph into a sprite.
That way , you can manipulate your text as a sprite.

Example code:

Note, this will return a Sprite of a single glyph. (E.g. char 'A' is transformed into a sprite.)

```
/** Creates a sprite from a glyph.
 * 
 * @param ch 
 * @return Sprite
 */
public Sprite getGlyphSprite (char ch) {

    Glyph glyph = Globals.g.font.getData().getGlyph(ch);
    Sprite s = new Sprite(Globals.g.font.getRegion().getTexture(),
            glyph.srcX,glyph.srcY,glyph.width, glyph.height);

    s.flip(false, true);
    s.setOrigin(glyph.width/2, glyph.height/2);

    return s;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't respect the character width and height, e.g if you take a " ' " char, it doesn't show it at the top, if you set ch as a space " ", it doesn't respect the space width.

Answer (score 1):

The first answer from Lunatikul didn't worked in my 2D case. It cuts my text to only a half letter. I was successfull with the following:

```
batch.begin();
batch.setTransformMatrix(new Matrix4().setToRotation(0,0,1,<insert angle here>));
font.draw(batch, "Hallo Welt", 100, 100);
batch.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just add.. I suppose you have font base image inside some atlas.. so you need to add TextureRegion originals sot gliph src as it is just relative  to that given Texture region so

```
BitmapFont font = ...
BitmapFont.Glyph glyph = font.getData().getGlyph(ch);
int srcX = glyph.srcX + font.getRegion().getRegionX();
int srcY = glyph.srcY+ font.getRegion().getRegionY();
Sprite s = new Sprite(font.getRegion().getTexture(), srcX,srcY,glyph.width, glyph.height);
```