# Libgdx how to animate a BitmapFont?

Tags: fonts, libgdx

Is possible to animate a `BitmapFont` in libgdx? For example, if I want to rotate a `BitmapFont`, do I have to flip the `BitmapFont`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really easy to do it in a scene2D. If you use a Label into a Stage, you can add actions to the label.

check this page.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d#actions

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508749/draw-a-bitmapfont-rotated-in-libgdx